# Parse String to double[]

Tags: java, regex, string, parsing

As can add all the values ​​of a string array being these positive or negative and then pass them to a double array.

Example: 
SUM VALUES
String sa_notas[] = {1, 5, -2}
RESULT (1+5-2) = 4

ERROR MENSSAGE:
at org.apache.harmony.luni.util.FloatingPointParser.initialParse(FloatingPointParser.java:149)
                                                                        at org.apache.harmony.luni.util.FloatingPointParser.parseDouble(FloatingPointParser.java:281)
                                                                        at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:318)
                                                                        at es.amedidaapp.gado.D_Anadir_Registro$3.afterTextChanged(D_Anadir_Registro.java:176)

Thanks for the help

code:

```
if (s.length() > 0) {
        s_contains_notas = et_notas.getText().toString();
        if (b_calculadora) {

            if (s_contains_notas.length() <= 0 || !s_contains_notas.matches("[^0-9]+")) {
                s_contains_notas = s_contains_notas.replace("+", " ");//separate positives numbers
                s_contains_notas = s_contains_notas.replaceAll("[^0-9, -]", ""); //delete letters
                s_contains_notas = s_contains_notas.replace(",", "."); //change format numbers
                s_contains_notas = s_contains_notas.replace("-", " -"); //separate negatives numbers

                String sa_notas[] = s_contains_notas.split(" "); //{1, 5, -2}
                double[] d_notas = new double[sa_notas.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < d_notas.length; i++) {
                    d_notas[i] = Double.parseDouble(sa_notas[i]); //ERROR to write negative numbers
                }
                double d_sum_notas = 0;
                for (Double d : d_notas) {
                    d_sum_notas += d;
                }
                s_euros = String.valueOf(d_sum_notas);
                et_euros.setText(nf_locale.format(d_sum_notas));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.
If I remove the dividers between the these numbers they were joining.(152)

Comment: What is your problem? What result do you get?

Comment: When I write negative numbers, on having spent it to double it gives mistake

Comment: You seem to be adding whitespaces in front of `-`, which may give empty strings when `split()`ing. But please show your input string, the actual sa_notas[] contents and the value that causes the exception.

Comment: actual sa_notas[] = [1, 5, -] ERROR input - to -2   MESSAGE org.apache.harmony.luni.util.FloatingPointParser.parseDouble(FloatingPointParser.java:281) at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:318) at es.amedidaapp.gado.D_Anadir_Registro$3.afterTextChanged(D_Anadir_Registro.java:176)

Comment: `if (s_contains_notas.length() <= 0` doesn't look right.

Comment: What is your input string?

Comment: sorry input not. i write - to -2

Comment: The problem is on having written the negative of the negative number, which on having spent it to the double goes out the mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved

CODE:

```
 if (s_contains_notas.length() <= 0 || !s_contains_notas.matches("[^0-9]+")) {

                list = new ArrayList<>();
                Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("[-]?[0-9]+(?:[,.][0-9]+)?");

                s_contains_notas = s_contains_notas.replaceAll("," , ".");
                Matcher m = PATTERN.matcher(s_contains_notas);
                while (m.find()) {
                    list.add(m.group());

                }

                double[] d_notas = new double[list.size()]; //create an array with the size of the failList

                for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i) { //iterate over the elements of the list
                    d_notas[i] = Double.parseDouble(list.get(i)); //store each element as a double in the array
                }

                double d_sum_notas = 0;
                for (Double d : d_notas) {
                    d_sum_notas += d;
                }

                s_euros = String.valueOf(d_sum_notas);
                et_euros.setText(nf_locale.format(d_sum_notas));
            }
```

OUTPUT:
1
-1
0.5
-0.5
0,5

Answer (score 1):

How about a little different approach?

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class RegEx {

  // Example input:
  final static private String NUMBERS = "Data: 0,5€ -0.1$ 9 -3  #3";

  // Regular expression to match floating point numbers:
  final static private Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("[-]?[0-9]+(?:[,.][0-9]+)?");

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    final Matcher m = PATTERN.matcher(NUMBERS);

    while ( m.find() ) {
      System.out.println(m.group());
    }

  }

}
```

Output:

```
0,5
-0.1
9
-3
3
```

Comment: how sum values?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks JimmyB for guiding me,

Next problem, the new code fail to decimals.

NEW CODE

```
 if (s_contains_notas.length() <= 0 || !s_contains_notas.matches("[^0-9]+")) {

                List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
                Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("[-]?[0-9]+(?:[,.][0-9]+)?");
                Matcher m = PATTERN.matcher(s_contains_notas);
                while ( m.find() ) {
                    list.add(m.group());
                }

                double[] d_notas = new double[list.size()]; //create an array with the size of the list

                for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i) { //iterate over the elements of the list
                    d_notas[i] = Double.parseDouble(list.get(i)); //store each element as a double in the array
                }

                double d_sum_notas = 0;
                for (Double d : d_notas) {
                    d_sum_notas += d;
                }
                s_euros = String.valueOf(d_sum_notas);
                et_euros.setText(nf_locale.format(d_sum_notas));
```